# Remove method for Stack in Java

Tags: java, stack

I am struggling to figure this out - I need to implement a method:
public int remove(int n)
where I remove the top most n entries from my stack. Any suggestions on where I can start to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code provided where I need to implement this remove() method.

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements StackInterface<T>
{
private Node topNode; // references the first node in the chain

   public LinkedStack()
   {
      topNode = null;
   } // end default constructor

public void push(T newEntry)
{
   Node newNode = new Node(newEntry, topNode);   topNode = newNode;
} // end push

public T peek()
{
   T top = null;
   if (topNode != null)
   top = topNode.getData();
   return top;
} // end peek

public T pop()
{
    T top = peek();
   if (topNode != null)
   topNode = topNode.getNextNode();
   return top;
} // end pop

public boolean isEmpty() {
   return topNode == null;
}
public void clear() {
   topNode = null;
}

private class Node
{
  private T    data; // entry in stack
  private Node next; // link to next node

  private Node(T dataPortion)
  {
     this(dataPortion, null);
     } // end constructor

  private Node(T dataPortion, Node nextNode)
  {
     data = dataPortion;
     next = nextNode;
      } // end constructor

  private T getData()
  {
     return data;
  } // end getData

  private void setData(T newData)
  {
     data = newData;
  } // end setData

  private Node getNextNode()
  {
     return next;
  } // end getNextNode

  private void setNextNode(Node nextNode)
  {
     next = nextNode;
  } // end setNextNode
 } // end Node
} // end LinkedStack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial solution is just to call `this.pop()` `n` times. For this, you need to use a loop.

Seems like your homework, so I'm not going to show a code example.

Comment: this is HW - sorry, I should have mentioned that, but I just needed a starting point and you helped with that. Thanks!